# Amazon-s3 : Trying to get s3 work after overwriting the file

Tags: amazon-s3, coldfusion, lucee

I am using Lucee to connect with s3. I can upload files to s3 with no problem. Only issue I am facing is, when I have to overwrite the file. I am trying to add a detection mechanism that if file already exists, either it should download that file on my local or make a backup in s3 itself and upload my file to overwrite the original file. So meta information should stay intact.

by backup I mean copy of the original

The code for Uploading is:

```
<cffile action="upload" file="s3://mykeysfolder/folder1.js">
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not just use the versioning feature in S3?

Comment: versioning, i am not sure if it, how to use it, do you have blog post or entry that explains it

Comment: and is the versioning can be enabled at admin lvel or user level, i am no admin and no rights, but i can upload files/

Comment: See: [Using Versioning - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html) It is configured at the bucket level.

Comment: thanks, but can't do it on s3, because those are not in my control